# Making a Canvas JS Game Mobile friendly

Tags: javascript, canvas, mobile, game-development

https://flappy-pappy.netlify.app/
How do you make canvas games mobile friendly? I know that you can make the page with a link to app store and create the app with swift but I'm talking about how can you make this responsive with Js on mobile? I'm thinking about implementing some sort of joystick approach using this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Control_mechanisms/Mobile_touch.

**I don't understand why it has lag on mobile, around 500ms lag when you tap it.**
**Also I tried it on different devices and on my device it goes at normal speed and on other phones the pace is way faster.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about tags. You need meta tags. It still feels a bit laggy but maybe touch events will do it. Thank you for the dislikes. Love you all.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"
/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta
  name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style"
  content="black-translucent"
/>
```

Comment: The dislikes were probably because this was not the exact same question they were looking for.